# Why is while (is.null(...)) often combined with num_to_schoice?

Tags: r-exams

Why is the while loop necessary in the following code chunk? Taken from the [dist3](http://www.R-exams.org/templates/dist3/) exercise provided in the R/exams package.

```
sc <- NULL
while (is.null(sc)) {
  p <- c(sample(1:3, 1), sample(1:5, 1))
  q <- c(sample(4:5, 1), sample((1:5)[-p[2]], 1))
  sol <- sqrt(sum((p - q)^2))

  err <- c(sqrt(sum((p + q)^2)), sqrt(sum(abs(p - q))))
  err <- err[abs(err - sol) > 0.1]
  if (length(err) > 1) err <- sample(err, 1)

  sc <- num_to_schoice(sol, wrong = err,
    range = c(0.1, 10), delta = 0.3, digits = 3)
}
```

Comment: Could you please describe what "doubts" you have? Are there any erros? Does the loop not what it should do?

Answer (score 1):

In general the function `num_to_schoice()` - that in this example is responsible for updating the variable `sc` upon which the while loop conditions - is not guaranteed to return a list with `$questions` texts and corresponding logical `$solutions`. Instead, it may return `NULL` along with a warning when it cannot set up the questions/solutions with the properties specified (range, minimum distance, etc.). See below for some illustrations.

Therefore, to guarantee that an exercise that relies on `num_to_schoice()` always yields a valid solution, the single-choice list `sc` is first initialized with `NULL` and then parameters are resampled and `num_to_schoice()` recalled until `sc` is not `NULL` anymore (but a list with questions/solutions). *(Remark: I use this setup routinely in my own exercises and often do not check whether any problems may actually occur. In this particular setup it seems that the problem with a NULL value can never occur.)*

For illustration, consider the following simple examples where the correct solution is 10, we want a `delta` of at least 1 between the correct and any false solution, and we use different ranges for the false solutions.

- First, let's use the range [1, 20] which always finds some set of false solutions.

  ```
  set.seed(2021)
  num_to_schoice(10, range = c(1, 20), delta = 1, digits = 0)
  ## $solutions
  ## [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
  ## 
  ## $questions
  ## [1] "$16$" "$17$" "$7$"  "$10$" "$13$"
  ```
- In contrast, the interval [9, 11] is never large enough for four false solutions with a minimal distance of 1.

  ```
  num_to_schoice(10, range = c(9, 11), delta = 1, digits = 0)
  ## NULL
  ## Warning message:
  ## In num_to_schoice(10, range = c(9, 11), delta = 1, digits = 0) :
  ##   specified 'range' is too small for 'delta'
  ```
- Finally, the interval [7, 13] may or may not be large enough. This depends on an initial step carried out in `num_to_schoice()` where the function first decides how many of the four false solutions should be on the left vs. on the right of the correct solution. This is built into the function to avoid systematically generating question lists where the correct solution is (one of) the smallest or (one of) the largest.

  ```
  num_to_schoice(10, range = c(7, 13), delta = 1, digits = 0)
  ## $solutions
  ## [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
  ## 
  ## $questions
  ## [1] "$7$"  "$13$" "$10$" "$11$" "$9$" 
  num_to_schoice(10, range = c(7, 13), delta = 1, digits = 0)
  ## NULL
  ## Warning message:
  ## In num_to_schoice(10, range = c(7, 13), delta = 1, digits = 0) :
  ##   specified 'range' is too small for 'delta'
  ```

More impossible setups can occur when `wrong` solutions are pre-specified that are too close to the correct solution and/or make the interval too small etc. See the examples in `?num_to_schoice` for more illustrations.